# Can Microsoft find out about my unregistered programs when Windows is automatically updated?

Tags: windows

Are automatic updates safe?

If for example I have a registered version of Windows and some other unregistered programs, can Microsoft find out about those unregistered programs while performing automatic updates of Windows and vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how paranoid you are.  There's no way to be absolutely certain that Microsoft doesn't gather just about any kind of information from your computer while Windows or Microsoft Update are running.  Their privacy statements disclaim any such activity, but they could start doing it any time and you'd never know.  I use Microsoft Update, but I don't use Windows' automatic update feature - I run MS Update manually.  If you're really worried, you can always download and install individual patches and stay away from Windows/Microsoft Update.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic Windows Update will only update Microsoft products, yes it is safe.